# sqlAlchemy mapper not defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "alchemyTest.py", line 12, in <module>
planetMapper = mapper(Planet, planet)
NameError: name 'mapper' is not defined
```

My SQLAlchemy version is 1.0.12. I am using the following code:

```
connection = db.connect();
metadata = MetaData(db);

class Planet(object):
    pass

planet = Table('PLANET', metadata, autoload=True)
planetMapper = mapper(Planet, planet)
```

I have searched online and have not been able to find anything on mapper not being defined. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, did you import `mapper`?

Comment: I am using `from sqlalchemy import *`. Do I need to import mapper in a separate statement? Sorry I am pretty in experienced with python and sqlalchemy.

Comment: Here's what you need to do. Figure out which module `mapper` is in, then import it from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper
```